# Configuration in Azure AD B2C for Custom Policies

Tags: azure-ad-b2c, identity-experience-framework

How do I use a "config file" in custom policies?  Like [`appsetting.json`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/fundamentals/configuration/?tabs=basicconfiguration) in ASP.Net Core.

Things to configure

- `TenantId`
- `<LoadUri>` for [customizing the UI](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory-b2c/active-directory-b2c-ui-customization-custom)

---

**Background:** we have multiple B2C tenants for each environment (Local, Dev, QA, Prod, etc.).  We need to promote the custom policies from `Local -> Dev -> ...`.  As it stands now, we have to modify the policies when promoting.

I'm hoping there is something like [pulling `Keys`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory-b2c/active-directory-b2c-app-registration#create-a-web-app-client-secret) from the B2C app.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you are using Visual Studio Code, the [Azure AD B2C extension](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=AzureADB2CTools.aadb2c) can do this for you using an appsettings.json file.

Here is a quote from the extension page in the `Policy Settings` section:

> When you execute the B2C Policy build command, the VS Code extension finds and replaces the values of your settings with the ones configured in the policy file, and creates a directory that contains all of your policy files (after the replacement).

Answer (score 2):

There is currently nothing like the `Policy Keys` to enable environment to environment variable substitution for `TenantId`, `LoadUri` etc. in the Azure Portal.

Some potential approaches:

**1)** [SlowCheetah](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=VisualStudioProductTeam.SlowCheetah-XMLTransforms) is a Visual Studio 2015/17 tool that allows transformations to be made on XML files. You can utilize this to create an XML transformation file for each B2C policy and environment you have.

For example, you create a UAT transformation file for your `B2C_1A_SignIn` policy and configure all the variables you need. You then select UAT as the output environment and press F5 to build. This will output a transformed file to your applications `bin` folder. You will now have all the correct values for UAT, which you can upload to the Azure Portal.

---

**2)** [Replace Tokens from Visual Studio Team Services Build and Release.](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=qetza.replacetokens) This approach allows you to set all your variables as tokens in your policies. You would then initialize a build and release through VSTS and all your defined tokens will be replaced. This approach does require access to VSTS and the setup of code management, build and release. You would also need an output of the build files, e.g. a storage table or file directory on a server.

---

**3)** VSTS Build & Release: [File transforms and variable substitution reference](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/vsts/build-release/tasks/transforms-variable-substitution).

Answer (score 1):

The VS Code extension does support this. You can add as many settings under PolicySettings as you would like to.

```
{
    "Environments": [
        {
            "Name": "...",
            "Production": true,
            "Tenant": "...",
            "PolicySettings": {
                "ProxyIdentityExperienceFrameworkId": "...",
                "LoadUri": "https://myhosted/template",
                "somekey" : "some value"
            }
        }
    ]
}
```

You reference it using {Setting:LoadUri-signuporsignin}, do not include PolicySettings. [Extensions description](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=AzureADB2CTools.aadb2c)